# R - brevity when subsetting?

Tags: r

I'm still new to R and do all of my subsetting via the pattern:
data[ command that produces logical with same length as data ]

or
subset( data , command that produces logical with same length as data )

for example:

```
test = c("A", "B","C")
ignore = c("B")
result = test[ !( test %in% ignore ) ]
result = subset( test , !( test %in% ignore ) )
```

But I vaguely remember from my readings that there's a shorter/(more readable?) way to do this?  Perhaps using the "with" function?

Can someone list alternative to the example above to help me understand the options in subsetting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of a more succinct way of subsetting for your specific example, using only vectors. What you may be thinking of, regarding `with`, is subsetting data frames based on conditions using columns from that data frame. For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(variable1 = runif(10), variable2 = letters[1:10])
```

If we want grab a subset of `dat` based on a condition using `variable1` we could do this:

```
dat[dat$variable1 < 0,]
```

or we can save ourselves having to write `dat$*` each time by using `with`:

```
with(dat,dat[variable1 < 0,])
```

Now, you'll notice that I really didn't save any keystrokes by doing that in this case. But if you have a data frame with a long name, and a complicated condition it can save you a bit. See also the related `?within` command if you're altering the data frame in question.

Alternatively, you can use `subset` which can do essentially the same thing:

```
subset(dat, variable1 < 0)
```

`subset` can also handle conditions on the columns via the select argument.

Answer (score 3):

The `with` function would help if test were a column in a data frame (or object in a list), but with global vectors with does not help.

Some people have created a not in operator that could save a couple of key strokes from what you did.  If all the values in test are unique then the `setdiff` function may be what you are thinking of (but if for example you had multiple `"A"`s then `setdiff` would only return 1 of them).

With your ignore being only 1 value you could use `test != ignore`, but that does not generalize to ignore having 2 or more values.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen timed comparisons of alternate methods and %in% (based on match) was one of the best performing strategies.

Alternates:

```
test[!test=="B"]   #logical indexing
test[which(test != "B")]  #numeric indexing
  # the which() is not superfluous when there are NA's if you want them ignored
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to the original example:

```
test[test != ignore]
```

Other ways, using joran's example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(variable1 = runif(10), variable2 = letters[1:10])
```

Returning one column: `df[[1]]`. df$name is [equivalent to](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) df[["name", exact = FALSE]]

```
df[df[[1]] < 0.5, ] 
df[df["variable1"] < 0.5, ]
```

Returning one data frame of one column: `df[1]`

```
df[df[1] < 0.5, ]
```

Using `with`

```
with(df, df[df[[1]] < 0.5, ]) # One column
with(df, df[df["variable1"] < 0.5, ]) # One column
with(df, df[df[1] < 0.5, ])  # data frame of one column
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, variable1 < 0.5)
```